# Java non-prime numbers

Tags: java, arrays, loops, primes

I want to print non-prime numbers in an interval and calculate the quantity of numbers. For example, between 3 and 10, the non-prime numbers are 4,6,8,9 for this interval.

I created an array and put the nonprime numbers into the array. I can print them on the screen but when I tried to reach every single element on the array `nonPrime[0]` and `nonPrime[1]` seems `0`. Also I need enough dimension array because it doesn't help to calculate the quantity of non-prime numbers.

That's what I tried:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{       
    int x=10;//end of the interval
    int y=2;//first of the interval
    int[]nonPrime=new int[10];
    for(int i=y+1;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(int j=2;j<x;j++)
        {  
            if(i!=j)
            {
                if((i%j==0))
                {
                   nonPrime[j]=i;
                   break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a List instead of an array; that way you don't have to know the size beforehand.

Comment: Are you sure, that your prime algorithm is correct? Additionally, an array does not seem to be the best choice as you usually do not know the amount of primes or non-primes in a range of numbers. Use a list instead.

Comment: *nonPrime[0] and nonPrime[1] seems 0* – and what do you expect? You address array with `j` variable, which runs from 2 to `x`. Sure thing indexes 0 and 1 would never be set, hence will have theirs default values. You also can run your inner loop until `j<=i/2` (and only odd numbers too) instead of `j<x`: saves a few iterations and removes unnecessary condition check.

Comment: can you write a simple code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a ArrayList instead of an int array like this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public static void main (String[] args)
{       
    int x=10;//end of the interval
    int y=2;//first of the interval
    ArrayList<Integer> nonPrime = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=y+1;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(int j=2;j<i;j++)
        {  
            if((i%j==0))
            {
               nonPrime.add(i);
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are mistakes so i cant run in java